# String.valueOf() vs. Object.toString()

Tags: java, string

In Java, is there any difference between `String.valueOf(Object)` and `Object.toString()`?
Is there a specific code convention for these?

Comment: Primitive types don't have a "toString".. so `String.valueOf` is used. For objects that override toString, I think String.valueOf might call that instead. Not sure about that part though.

Comment: @Brandon You are correct, it does exactly that, except that it checks for `null` first.

Comment: The first comment here I think makes the most sense if it is correct. You must use  String.valueOf in certain situations where the target is a primitive type.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

According to [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-), `String.valueOf()` returns:

> if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

So there shouldn't really be a difference except for an additional method invocation.

Also, in the case of `Object#toString`, if the instance is `null`, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown, so arguably, it's less *safe*.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    String str = null;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(str));  // This will print a String equal to "null"        
    System.out.println(str.toString()); // This will throw a NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Read and rely on the javadocs, not the code.  (The code could in principle be different for different versions / releases of Java.)

Comment: @Brandon - Incorrect.  It only needs to change if the **behaviour** changes in a way that invalidates the javadoc.  1) The chances of that happening for this method are ZERO. They won't make a change that warranted a change in the spec, and if they did then they *would* change the spec.  2) It doesn't invalidate my advice.  If you read the javadoc, then you will see that the documented behaviour has changed!

Comment: Wouldn't the method that throws the exception be *more* safe? Usually, when your code throws a NullPointerException, it's sort of a good thing. It may not feel good to the developer in the moment ("aww, no, now I need to go back and fix my code"), but since the error was thrown, you found out you needed to fix something. Left the other way, you're exposing the "null" directly to the user and not getting an error reported unless you explicitly check for one, which seems to me less safe.

Comment: Try using both valueOf and toString on a char array and feast your eyes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't actually call `String.valueOf(null)`, that's an NPE. It only works for objects that are null.

Comment: @Stephen C I determined this by testing. I just reproduced it on repl.it. https://repl.it/repls/CapitalScrawnyBootstrapping The documentation refers to things that are Objects, which `null` is not.

Comment: That's not the explanation. The `String.valueOf(null)` actually resolves to the `valueOf(char[])` overload.  This is because `char[]` is a more specific type than `Object`.

Comment: what if there's no toString() method for the object?

Answer (score 26):

**Differences between String.valueOf(Object) and Object.toString() are:**

**1)** **If string is null,**

*`String.valueOf(Object)` will return `"null"`, whereas `Object::toString()` will throw a null pointer exception.*

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
    String str = null;
    
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(str));  // it will print null        
    System.out.println(str.toString()); // it will throw NullPointerException        
}
```

**2) Signature:**

*valueOf() method of String class is static. whereas toString() method of String class is non static.*

The signature or syntax of string's valueOf() method is given below:

```
public static String valueOf(boolean b)  
public static String valueOf(char c)  
public static String valueOf(char[] c)  
public static String valueOf(int i)  
public static String valueOf(long l)  
public static String valueOf(float f)  
public static String valueOf(double d)  
public static String valueOf(Object o)
```

The signature or syntax of string's `toString()` method is given below:

```
public String toString()
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(null)` is `"null"`, not `null`.

Comment: @ElectricShadow [It's actually an NPE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465731/string-valueof-vs-object-tostring#comment97161689_27465774)

Comment: @Leponzo No it's not. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @ElectricShadow Please read the comment I linked and **try it out**. `String.valueOf(null)` gives an NPE, but `Object o = null; System.out.println(String.valueOf(o))` prints `null`.

Answer (score 21):

> In Java, is there any difference between String.valueOf(Object) and Object.toString()?

Yes.  (And more so if you consider overloading!)

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) explains, `String.valueOf((Object) null)` will be treated as a special case by the `valueOf` method and the value `"null"` is returned.  By contrast, `null.toString()` will just give you an NPE.

### Overloading

It turns out that `String.valueOf(null)` (note the difference!) *does* give an NPE ... despite the javadoc.  The real explanation<sup>1</sup> is obscure:

1. There are a number of overloads of `String.valueOf`, but there are two that are relevant here: `String.valueOf(Object)` and `String.valueOf(char[])`.
2. In the expression `String.valueOf(null)`, both of those overloads are *applicable*, since `null` is assignment compatible with any reference type.
3. When there are two or more *applicable* overloads, the JLS says that the overload for the *most specific* argument type is chosen.
4. Since `char[]` is a subtype of `Object`, it is *more specific*.
5. Therefore the `String.valueOf(char[])` overload is called.
6. `String.valueOf(char[])` throws an NPE if its argument is a null array.  Unlike `String.valueOf(Object)`, it doesn't treat `null` as a special case.

Another example illustrates the difference in the `valueOf(char[])` overload even more clearly:

```
char[] abc = new char[]('a', 'b', 'c');
System.out.println(String.valueOf(abc));  // prints "abc"
System.out.println(abc.toString());       // prints "[C@...."
```

---

> Is there a specific code convention for these?

No.

Use which ever is most appropriate to the requirements of the context in which you are using it.  (Do you *need* the formatting to work for `null`?)

Note: that isn't a code convention.  It is just common sense programming.  It is *more important* that your code is *correct* than it is to follow some stylistic convention or "best practice" dogma<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - You can confirm this by using `javap -c` to examine the code of a method that has a `String.valueOf(null)` call.  Observe the overload that is used for the call.</sup>

<sup>2 - Please read ["No Best Practices"](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164), and pass this reference on to the next person who tells you that it is "best practice" to do something in the programming or IT domains.</sup>

---

### Personal opinion

Some developers acquire the (IMO) bad habit of "defending" against nulls.  So you see lots of tests for nulls, and treating nulls as special cases.  The idea seems to be prevent NPE from happening.

I think this is a bad idea.  In particular, I think it is a bad idea if what you do when you find a `null` is to try to "make good" ... without consideration of why there was a `null` there.

In general, it is better to avoid the `null` being there in the first place ... unless the `null` has a very specific meaning in your application or API design.  So, rather than avoiding the NPE with lots of defensive coding, it is better to let the NPE happen, and then track down and fix the source of the unexpected `null` that triggered the NPE.

So how does this apply here?

Well, if you think about it, using `String.valueOf(obj)` *could* be a way of "making good".  That is to be avoided.  If it is unexpected for `obj` to be `null` in the context, it is better to use `obj.toString()`.

Answer (score 7):

Most has already been mentioned by other answers, but I just add it for completeness:

1. Primitives don't have a `.toString()` as they are not an implementation of the `Object`-class, so only `String.valueOf` can be used.
2. `String.valueOf` will transform a given object that is `null` to the String `"null"`, whereas `.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.
3. <s>The compiler will use `String.valueOf` by default when something like `String s = "" + (...);` is used. Which is why `Object t = null; String s = "" + t;` will result in the String `"null"`, and not in a NPE.</s> EDIT: Actually, it will use the `StringBuilder.append`, not `String.valueOf`. So ignore what I said here.

In addition to those, here is actually a use case where `String.valueOf` and `.toString()` have different results:

Let's say we have a generic method like this:

```
public static <T> T test(){
  String str = "test";
  return (T) str;
}
```

And we'll call it with an `Integer` type like this: `Main.<Integer>test()`.

When we create a String with `String.valueOf` it works fine:

```
String s1 = String.valueOf(Main.<Integer>test());
System.out.println(s1);
```

This will output `test` to STDOUT.

With a `.toString()` however, it won't work:

```
String s2 = (Main.<Integer>test()).toString();
System.out.println(s2);
```

This will result in the following error:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: class `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to class `java.lang.Integer`

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fZA9C8IwEIZ3f8XRKRkM6OhHdwdxsOAgDrGNNVpTyV0LIv72mhgFtdYsGZ679324g6xl/5AdmyYtJCLMpTbXHsC52hY6BSRJ7qtLncHJIbYkq02@3oC0OXLwowDLC5I6ibIicXaYCsOilaY9hGlRy6JSix1DsnwU8XFYejDAAUy/57yEmMwMqVzZmBQS46@tdhUOutmT@Pff1KkJKoMHa0sOneRvrbetbsPhg916rcNOkhgSCFHXj0ayrjLyJAq5VlFlDbCEexjybk1zBw)

As for why, I can refer to [this separated question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175130/java-generics-casts-strangely). In short however:

- When using `.toString()` it will first compile and evaluate the object, where the cast to `T` (which is an `String` to `Integer` cast in this case) will result in the `ClassCastException`.
- When using `String.valueOf` it will see the generic `T` as `Object` during compilation and doesn't even care about it being an `Integer`. So it will cast an `Object` to `Object` (which the compiler just ignores). Then it will use `String.valueOf(Object)`, resulting in a `String` as expected. So even though the `String.valueOf(Object)` will do a `.toString()` on the parameter internally, we've already skipped the cast and its treated like an `Object`, so we've avoided the `ClassCastException` that occurs with the usage of `.toString()`.

Just thought it was worth mentioning this additional difference between `String.valueOf` and `.toString()` here as well.

Comment: The last time I cared about this, which would have been around JDK 1.2, `("" + x)` compiled to `String.valueOf(x)`, but anything more complicated used a `StringBuffer` (we didn't have `StringBuilder` then).

Answer (score 4):

The most important difference is the way they handle null String references.

```
String str = null;
System.out.println("String.valueOf gives : " + String.valueOf(str));//Prints null
System.out.println("String.toString gives : " + str.toString());//This would throw a NullPointerExeption
```

Answer (score 3):

`String.valueOf(Object)` and `Object.toString()` are literally the same thing.

If you take a look at the implementation of [String.valueOf(Object)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), you'll see that `String.valueOf(Object)` is basically just a null-safe invocation of `toString()` of the appropriate object:

```
Returns the string representation of the Object argument.

Parameters:
    obj an Object.
Returns:
    if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; 
    otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.
See also:
    Object.toString()

public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Not true, use both valueOf and toString on a char array and feast your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

When argument is `null`, the `String.valueOf` returns `"null"`, but `Object.toString` throws `NullPointerException`, that's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more major difference between the two methods is when the object we are converting is an array.

When you convert an array using Object.toString() you will get some kind of garbage value(@ followed by hashcode of array).

To get a human-readable toString(), you must use String.valueOf(char[]); plz note that this method works only for Array of type char. I would recommend using Arrays.toString(Object[]) for converting arrays to String.

Second difference is when the object is null, ValueOf() returns a String "null", while toString() will return null pointer exception.

Comment: Hi @Tom this is true for an array of any type, However If you are using Arrays.toString(Object [ ] ), you can convert an array of any type to string.

Comment: Hi @Tom Object.toString() returning a garbage value is true for an array of any type, you are right that String.valueOf(Array) will give a correct string only for an array of char type. I should have mentioned that, thanks, I will edit it.

Comment: That isn't a garbage value, it is the classname and the hashcode ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)).

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf() can be used with primitive types which do not have toString() methods.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say exactly what the difference is but there appears to be a difference when operating at the byte level. In the following encryption scenario Object.toString() produced a value that couldn't be decrypted whereas String.valueOf() worked as intended ...

```
private static char[] base64Encode(byte[] bytes) 
{   
    return Base64.encode(bytes);
}

private static String encrypt(String encrypt_this) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
{
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));

     //THIS FAILED when attempting to decrypt the password
    //return base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(encrypt_this.getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString(); 

    //THIS WORKED
    return String.valueOf(base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(encrypt_this.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
}//end of encrypt()
```

Comment: Why failed? what's the problem?

Comment: The explanation is that you are actually calling `valueOf(char[])` rather than `valueOf(Object)`.  The behavior of `valueOf(char[])` is significantly different to `char[].toString()`.  But either way, this answer is not *apropos* because you are calling a different overload to the one the Question asks about.

Answer (score -2):

The below shows the implementation for java.lang.String.valueOf as described in the source for jdk8u25. So as per my comment, there's no difference. It calls "Object.toString". For primitive types, it wraps it in its object form and calls "toString" on it.

See below:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1994, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */


    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }

    public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
        return new String(data);
    }

    public static String valueOf(char data[], int offset, int count) {
        return new String(data, offset, count);
    }

    public static String copyValueOf(char data[], int offset, int count) {
        return new String(data, offset, count);
    }

    public static String copyValueOf(char data[]) {
        return new String(data);
    }

    public static String valueOf(boolean b) {
        return b ? "true" : "false";
    }

    public static String valueOf(char c) {
        char data[] = {c};
        return new String(data, true);
    }

    public static String valueOf(int i) {
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }

    public static String valueOf(long l) {
        return Long.toString(l);
    }

    public static String valueOf(float f) {
        return Float.toString(f);
    }

    public static String valueOf(double d) {
        return Double.toString(d);
    }
```