# NullPointerException if the JSON contains null

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I am having a little issue.

When I use JSON path to extract a value from a DTO like so:

```
public String recipientEmail() {
    String email = validatableResponse.extract().jsonPath().get("email[0]").toString();
    return email;
}
```

If that DTO contains a value like:

```
email: "test@gmail.com"
```

It works fine and outputs this value. However, if the value is `null` like so:

```
email: null
```

Then it gives me a `NullPointerException`. How can I fix this and be able to retrieve the `null`?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `toString` without checking if you have valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your `email` String contain the value `"null"`, then you should use the `String.valueOf()` method instead of the `.toString()` method. The difference is that `String.valueOf()` will return the String `"null"`, where `.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`, instead.

So your line could look like this:

```
String email = String.valueOf(validatableResponse.extract().jsonPath().get("email[0]"));
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465774/6214491) explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

What value should be returned, if your value is null?

At first I´d set the String to the value, wich should be returned when the result is null. Then I´d try to set the new value. If this fails, the method will return the value that was set first. Try and catch is used to avoid a crash when the NullPointer is thrown.

```
public String recipientEmail() {
String email="";
try{
    email = validatableResponse.extract().jsonPath().get("email[0]").toString();
}catch(NullPointerException ex){
ex.printStacktrace();
}
    return email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toString()` method is inside an object. If your object is a `null` then the jvm cannot find the `toString()` method. So `NullPointerException`.

Try,

```
String email = validatableResponse.extract().jsonPath().get("email[0]");

if(email == null){
   email = "null";
}else{
   email = email.toString();
}
```